# Arduino Due not executing code after power on

Tags: arduino-due, reset

My Arduino Due does not execute its code when powered on after being powered off for ten seconds or longer. I have to press the reset button for the code to execute.

I've read some older threads about a firmware issue and saw people doing solder jobs on their boards to fix it.

My question is, does this issue happen with all/any Arduino Due boards? Are just some clones (like mine) affected and the original works fine?

What's the best way to fix this problem? In this state the board serves no purpose anymore and I've downgraded to the Uno for now.

EDIT: Adding picture and link to the board used.
https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B016D5KYF6/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

[image]

Comment: you have posted inadequate information. what make of the board do you have? post a picture, maybe.

Comment: Nobody? It would help already to know if this issue is not "normal" for genuine Arduino Due boards.

Comment: It happens with UNOs as well. Have to press reset button to run any included program. Looking to fix this since the UNO has to start correctly when power is applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research I found out that

a) the issue applies to some Due boards only, not all

b) newer boards seem to have fixed the issue

c) there's a software (firmware update) and hardware (10k resistor) solution

I went with the hardware fix shown here:
http://www.dimdim.gr/2016/03/fixing-startup-issues-with-arduino-dues/

I did not have an SMD resistor at hand, so mine looks ancient but does the job.
Hope that helps others, too.

[image]

addendum:

The problem occurs only on some DUE boards and is due to some undocumented behaviour of the ATSAM3X8E processor combined with the behaviour of some MOSFETS installed on the DUE boards. So its occurence is largely a matter of luck.

The fix is simple: you just solder a 10K resistor across the top of this mosfet:

resistor about to be soldered on

[image]

resistor designated as R99

[image]

Comment: While the picture is great, it would be good if you could describe the fix in words so that it can still be applied by someone who might find your answer after the off-site link might have borken.